# TYPO3 7.6: Change fields on the fly in backend with window.opener.document

Tags: jquery, typo3, backend, wizard

How is it possible to change fields in parent window?

In TYPO3 6 it was possible to change with _hr at the end:

```
window.opener.document.getElementsByName("data["+ table +"][" + uid + "][field]_hr")[0].value = 123;
```

In TYPO3 7.6 I have only access to the hidden field and this field accept the new value only after save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That changed but know there is a data attribute which can be used. IMO it is something like

```
$('[data-formengine-input-name="' + fieldName + '"]');
```

Comment: This is best way with jQuery: 
$("input[data-formengine-input-name='data["+ table +"][" + uid + "]['YOUR_FIELD']",opener.document);